# Laravel 419 session expire issue after login. only on some hosting(local and few other live server working fine)

Tags: php, laravel, session, csrf

In laravel 5.7 when i'm trying to host on live server. I'm getting 419 session expired error as soon as I give login credentials and click login. It is working fine on localhost and few other live servers but I wanted to migrate to another new server and I got this issue.
-> I have tried csrf,dbconnected checks. storage permissions to 777 for storage/frameworks, tried commenting verifyCsrfToken middleware but redirects to login.
Not getting any solutions
test link-> https://breadtownbh.com/login

I'm trying to login but no matter whatever credentials I give whether right or wrong it just sends to 419 page.

Comment: If you've verified the csrf and other checks and still it doesn't work, then please consider your .htaccess file. There might be some rule written in it which is causing the issue.

Comment: <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]
</IfModule> this is my htaccess and my laravel is  "laravel/framework": "5.7.*",